# pylinting zopeish files: F0401: 11,0: Unable to import 'zope.interface'

Tags: plone, zope, pylint

I am trying to run pylint against source code polluted by Zope imports:

```
************* Module youraddon.interfaces
F0401: 11,0: Unable to import 'zope.interface'
```

The code in the question:

```
from zope.interface import Interface
```

And zope.interface egg is passed in sys.path for pylint as egg:

```
cat ../../bin/pylint|grep -i interface
'/fast/buildout-cache/eggs/zope.interface-3.6.7-py2.6-macosx-10.6-i386.egg',
```

Now the question is

- Can I make pylint import zope.interface in a way it understands it? Why it actually fails?
- If not, how can I supress import warnings and lint the rest of the file fine?

Also getting:

```
      # E0611: 11,0: No name 'interface' in module 'zope'
```

Comment: Sounds like pylint doesn't know about namespaces and is looking for zope.interface in the zope.components egg.

Comment: http://www.logilab.org/ticket/92792 filed by you ;-) You can also take the discussion to python-projects@lists.logilab.org

Comment: I quickly saw stackoverflow.com as a dead end for this issue >_<

Comment: Similar bug report: http://www.logilab.org/ticket/8796

Answer (score 1):

You can disable specific Pylint error message :

1) on the command line using --disable option

```
$ pylint --disable=F0401 youraddon.py
```

2) in the file adding a specific comment

```
#pylint: disable=F0401
```

http://www.logilab.org/card/pylint_manual

Comment: Thanks. I can disable error messages fine, but I'd like to pylint work as intended.

Answer (score 0):

I'd not install pylint globally but install it with the buildout you are installing your project with (assuming you are using buildout). You'd then add the instance eggs to the pylint part.

Something like this:

```
[buildout]
parts =
  instance
  pylint

[instance]
...
eggs =
  your.addon
  ...

[pylint]
recipe = zc.recipe.egg
entry-points = pylint=pylint.lint:Run
eggs =
  pylint
  ${instance:eggs}
```

A more complex example: https://github.com/4teamwork/ftw-buildouts/blob/master/test-base.cfg#L163

Cheers

Comment: Already doing, as stated, but pylint still does not find zope.interface http://miohtama.github.com/vvv/integration.html#integration-with-buildout-plone-zope